# Issue with javascript validation in netbeans

Tags: php, javascript, xampp, netbeans-7

I am new to `Netbeans`. I have created a simple `php` project. It consists of a form and I've written a separate `Javascript` file to validate its fields. I tried running the project outside netbeans, it works fine. I recently imported the project to netbeans but javascript doesn't seem to work well. When I try opening the page(form page) in the browser, the entire javascript file appears on the page.
I do not know where I'm going wrong. As I'm new to netbeans I am unable to rectify it. Kindly help.

My Javascript file is named `Validation.js` and is in the `js` folder.

```
function ValidateForm(theForm)
{
  //returns true/false after validation 
}
```

My php file looks similar to this.

```
<?php include "js/Validation.js"; 
  //if validation returns true
 if(isset($_POST))
 {
    if(isset ($_POST['bt_save']) && $_POST['bt_save'] == 'Submit')
    {
         //code to insert fields into database after validation
    }
 }
?>
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);">
 <!--form elements-->
 <input type="submit" name="bt_save" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your include is wrong, if you use php [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it just loads the page.

Try using `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Validation.js"></script>`. instead of `include "js/Validation.js"`.

So your new file would be something like.

```
<?php
  //if validation returns true
 if(isset($_POST))
 {
    if(isset ($_POST['bt_save']) && $_POST['bt_save'] == 'Submit')
    {
         //code to insert fields into database after validation
    }
 }
?>
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this);">
 <!--form elements-->
 <input type="submit" name="bt_save" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or alternatively in the above used PHP fashion try this : `<?php echo '<script>'; include "js/Validation.js"; echo '</script>';`. Dirty but will work.. ;)

Comment: @Tim Thank you.. It works now.. And yes it seems that the page gets loaded and that is the reason it gets displayed. However outside Netbeans it seems to work fine. Thanks again.